# How to deploy an Go application on GCP (Cloud run)?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-run

Created a simple Golang Application which has a server created via Gin web framework, which accepts a requests and provides responses for it. now to deploy it built a docker container and then host that on google cloud platform services that is cloud run.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/go

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check [this article out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines how to ask a good question and what types of questions are a good fit for StackOverflow. Your question is too generic, and doesn't contain any code or specific questions.

Answer (score 5):

Requirements -> Google Cloud SDK, Docker

- Step 1 -> Create a docker file for the application so that you can create an image from it and add to Container registry on GCP, from where one can use that container to deploy the application on cloud run.
  [dockerfile example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taPk9.png)
- Step 2 -> Build and run the container on local device to check for issues.
  [build and run on local device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caeBO.png)
- Step 3 -> Login to google cloud from terminal using command

  `gcloud auth login`

and also authorise docker-configure using command

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

- Step 4 -> Tag the image

  docker tag goapp gcr.io/project-name-from-GCP/go-app

Step 5 -> push your image onto container registry using commands

```
docker push gcr.io/project-name-from-GCP/go-app
```

[pushed image to Google container registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Eem.jpg)

- Step 6-> Use the above tagged image on google cloud run to create a service and deploy the application.

extra - if device is Mac M1 , then Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit. Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format , hence use --platform linux/amd64 in docker build to prevent issues while deployment on cloud run

Comment: Good answer.
To deploy it directly from VS Code, you might try this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtMIEtLQNa0

Found this to be simpler.

Comment: yeah this is simpler thanks mate .